# Script to send SMS through verzion

Tags: python, sms

I was wondering how could I send a SMS through my verzion number, with python? I've looked into, and concluded that you need to connect to the verizons SMTP for incoming & outgoing servers(?), but I am very confused on how I would register my number with this, and other things.

So, can the great wizards of python give me some help? Thank you..